# Not sure how to use AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm very new at this. I've read books to learn javascript and HTML, so unfortunately I haven't learn much about this.

I never used AJAX before, so not sure how it works, searched online, but find all examples too complicated.

Basically what I want to do is save a playlist (although not with cookies). Something everyone can see and add-on to it (similarly to a comments section).
This is just an example, I'm doing something else, but the html + js would be a bit big. Just want to know how I would do it on this, so that I could understand it (hopefully) and apply it elsewhere.

This would be the body and below it the code I have (currently all my code is in [head]):

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="songInput" size="40" placeholder="Song Name">
        <img id="addButton" src="button.png">
    </form>
    <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</body>

<script>
    window.onload = load;
    function load() {
        var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
        button.onclick = buttonClick;
    }
    function buttonClick() {
        var text = document.getElementById("songInput");
        var song = text.value;
        var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
        var add = document.createElement("li");
        add.innerHTML = song;
        var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
        ul.appendChild(add);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, did you try to google it? There are a lot of examples of using AJAX - [lmgtfy](http://bit.ly/17JgvGE)

Comment: So you have a database of some sort on the back? I suggest you take a look into this: https://togetherjs.com/ . That's about as simple as it gets. Another tip is to use jQuery for ajax and dom manipulation because it's very simple to learn and internet is full of jQuery tips and tricks.

Comment: Go through this...http://www.javatutorials.co.in/servlet-3-ajax-hello-world-example-using-jquery/
There are lot of examples over the net. Please google it.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand what AJAX is. AJAX is not a "tool" that you can use, instead, it's a name for the techniques (asynchronous JavaScript + XML). Basically it means "getting/posting data from/to server."

In vallina JavaScript, [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) lets you send and receive data to and from a server:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();          //Create an XMLHttpRequest object
xhr.open('get', url);                    //Set the type and URL
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){     //Tell it what to do with the data when state
                                         // changes
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){            //4 is the code for "finished"
         if(xhr.status === 200){         //Code 200 means "OK"
            //success
            var data = xhr.responseText; //Your data
        }else{
            //error                      //Deal with errors here
        }
    }
};
xhr.send(null);                          //After finished setting everything, send the
                                         // request. null here means we are not send-
                                         // ing anything to the server
```

It might look complicated, and `xhr` is repeated quite a lot. Not to mention the problems that [we have to deal with when executing in IE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Support_in_Internet_Explorer_versions_5.2C_5.5.2C_and_6).

There is solution for that. We will use libraries to simplify the process and let it do the hard works for us.

[In jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), this is what you have to do to for a basic `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { /*data here*/ },
    type: /*"GET" or "POST"*/
}).done(function(data){
    //success
}).fail(function(){
    //error
});
//Not complicated at all with jQuery
```

Since AJAX is a group of techniques to send/receive data, there're more ways to do the "same" thing. You might realize the code above only works for URL that has the same domain (pages on your server). To bypass that limitation, there's another technique called [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Sounds fancy, but what it means is simply "using the `<script>` tag to get pass that limitation". And of course, jQuery got you covered:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { /*data here*/ },
    type: /*"GET" or "POST"*/,
    dataType: "JSONP"               //specifying dataType to be JSONP
}).done(function(data){
    //success
});
```

Here is a simple example of getting content off Wikipedia using JSONP: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/dp8vtjvt/
With a normal `XMLHttpRequest` call to [Wikipedia's server](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) would not work. However by exploiting the fact that [`script` tags are not restricted by the Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access) we can achieve the same thing. Note that for JSONP to work, the server must be programmed internally to allow returning a JSON with wrapped callback call.